# 105 11-speed Crankset & Brake Caliper Compatibility w/ 2400 Claris Groupset

Tags: brakes, chain, crankset, chainring, compatibility

I have a **2016 Bianchi Via Nirone 7 with a 2400 2x8 Claris groupset**.

A buddy of mine is "upgrading" in stages and is letting go of his 105 components at a VERY reasonable price. Great timing too because my bottom bracket and brakes just kicked the bucket.

I want to continue biking since this is my only bike, so...

1. If I got his 105 crankset (FC-R7000 175x50/34) and bottom bracket (BBR60), could I install them on my bike? I know there's some difference in chain spacing and that the chain is more liable to rub on the inside of the bigger chainrings in the small/small crossover gears, but those are gears I shouldn't be using anyways. As long as it is a 175x50/34 crank, it shouldn't be a major problem right? My current crankset is a FC-RS200 with a BB-UN26 68mm 113mm bottom bracket.

   This guy installed a 11-speed Ultegra crank on his 8-speed Claris and it seems to work:
2. Also, will the 105 BR-R7000 Brake Calipers work with my ST-2400 Brifters?

If anyone else has attempted this, please chime in. Any insight will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Just check that the callipers use the same type of mount (not direct mount).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, and you understand what the potential downside can be. I wouldn't totally assume the chain rub will only happen on useless gears. I've also seen situations where it's not only rubbing but also picking inadvertently, which can be more of a hazard. Usually you can eliminate those issues and also make the front derailleur adjustment a little easier and better by using chainring spacers to gap the rings closer to what the 8 speed components expect. I use a Wheels Mfg 0.6mm spacer most of the time for all these applications and one set of them is usually good. Some companies have made 0.1mm. For R7000 you want to put them under the little ring if possible because it will make screw up the flowy contours of the big ring otherwise.
2. Yes, R7000 and 2400 are both Super SLR groups, so they match.